# Deploy bytecode

Tags: web3js, contract-deployment

I have a compiled contract (actually it's just arbitrary data) that I would like to store as an account.

It is possible to store this as a new account using web3js?

I do NOT have a constructor function. I just have the raw bytes.

Or is there some way I can translate the raw bytes into a constructor function that I can run?

---

My plan is to run this with Metamask.

Comment: I don't think that is possible because the compiler doesn't compile the contract but rather compiles a transaction which will then create the contract. May I ask why you want to store arbitrary data on the blockchain?

Comment: Maybe start a dark web

Comment: It should be possible but you need an special constructor that returns your data as contract code. For more technical details see this article https://medium.com/@hayeah/diving-into-the-ethereum-vm-part-5-the-smart-contract-creation-process-cb7b6133b855.

Comment: @Full Decent Starting a dark web will not work. Storing data on the blockchain costs literally millions of dollars per GB. Use an already existing distributed dark web solution like IPFS!

Comment: I calculate that you can deploy 10kb for 3 mil gas ($5). Not bad, here's some things you can do with just 1kb: https://js1k.com/

Comment: @FullDecent The code of a smart contract is not directly accesible and cannot be modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible but you need an special constructor that returns your data as contract code. From the article [Diving Into The Ethereum VM Part 5 — The Smart Contract Creation Process](https://medium.com/@hayeah/diving-into-the-ethereum-vm-part-5-the-smart-contract-creation-process-cb7b6133b855)

> The deploy code has two main purposes:
>
> - Runs the constructor function, and sets up initial storage variables (like contract owner).
> - Calculates the contract code, and returns it to the EVM.

The deploy code generated by the Solidity Compiler loads the contract from bytecode into memory, then returns it as the contract code.

But the data stored like this is not directly accessible. You can access them with [web3.eth.getCode](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgetcode) you cannot modify it, nor make more advanced queries.